# "Business" Software Metrics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metrics

I'm looking for a service (or gem) that will enable me to create a track software-produced business metrics.  I should clarify what I'm looking for, because this might be me failing at articulating what I'm looking for in Google.  Basically, based on the context of my software, I want to be able to emit certain values and then have them accumulate as metrics.  These are not performance or request metrics, per se, and certainly not code-quality metrics.

The quintessential use case is: suppose I have an if / else block in my code, I'd like to publish a metric that tells me how often I choose the true block vs the false block.

Or, suppose I'm using delayed_job, I'd like to publish how often jobs run and how many are in the queue on each run.

I can find all the metrics I want in code, I'm just not sure where to put them right now.

AWS cloudwatch has an api to publish your own metrics.  New Relic does, too.  However, both look expensive and give me a whole lots I'm not looking for (all the host metrics and code profiling).

Are there other services out that that offer this kind of functionality?

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this, I ended up going with Librato for all my metric needs.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually a couple of services that offer this functionality.  My company's product, [Instrumental](http://instrumentalapp.com) sounds like it might be a great fit for you - we've got a [Ruby client](https://github.com/fastestforward/instrumental_agent/) as well as some [extra tools](https://github.com/fastestforward/instrumental_tools/) for measuring system level stuff among other things.

If you're up for hosting your own stats collecting services, many people use the [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/)/[Statsd](https://github.com/etsy/statsd) combination; it takes a bit to set up and maintain, but it can definitely accomplish what you're looking to do here as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you're looking for some form of event tracking (as in, how often a part of your code gets used as opposed to another part). If that's right, you might want to give [Mixpanel](http://mixpanel.com/) a look.

Comment: mmmm.  definitely on the right track, though very tied to the paradigm of page tracking.  It appears to be very binary -- by that I mean that it is tracking events that happen or do not.  Ideally I'd like to be able to record an actual value or reading.  I'm not sure how I could record how many jobs I have in the queue for delayed_job with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should see NewRelic (APM or Insights modules) or Microsoft Insights, they allow you to create custom metrics (business metrics) inside your source code and monitor them online using dashboards.

Comment: New relic was too expensive. I never considered looking at a Microsoft product as we're an open source stack on Linux.